# Intellij Idea Dart SQL Injection

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

Intellij Idea has this feature called Language Injection, which allows you to have syntax highlighting for one language into another, such as having syntax highlighting for SQL inside a String when editing a java file.

I want to allow this to work with Dart, i.e. allow me to syntax highlight Strings with SQL in Dart automatically when I call a certain function. However this is not possible, as the only languages it allows injection FROM are those:

[image: language inject]

Is it possible to allow injections in a dart (or just for the sake of it any custom language), and if it isn't what resources can I look into for writing a plugin to do this, or modifying the existing built-in IntelliLang plugin?

EDIT:

I'm very well aware that it can be done manually for each string by pressing alt+enter, selecting inject language or reference and selecting sql, but this is unnecessarily tedious

Answer (score 2):

See the comments here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38875

Here are some quotes:

> currently we only support injection by comment for the string literal on the next line.

> It's possible to write a custom IntelliJ / WebStorm plugin with `MultiHostInjector` implementation that would support any custom annotation or whatever syntax for injection in Dart string literals.